# ConfigurationSection class (.Net) difficulty

Tags: .net, configurationmanager

I'm having difficulty making this ConfigurationSection implementation work. The goal here is to have a configurable map of file extensions to MIME file types. I followed two tutorials trying to arrive at this design, and never got either to work. I suspect it is because the call `ConfigurationManager.GetSection("extensionFiletypes") as FilenameExtensionTypeConfiguration` returns `null`. What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

**App.config**

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="extensionFiletypes" type="Models.Config.FilenameExtensionTypeConfiguration, Models.Config"/>
    </configSections>
    <extensionFiletypes>
        <collection>
            <add extension="acx" type="application/internet-property-stream" />
            <add extension="ai" type="application/postscript" />
            ...
            <add extension="z" type="application/x-compress" />
            <add extension="zip" type="application/zip" />
        </collection>
    </extensionFiletypes>
</configuration>
```

**Classes:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Models.Config
{
    public sealed class FilenameExtensionTypeConfiguration : ConfigurationSection
    {
        public static FilenameExtensionTypeConfiguration GetConfiguration()
        {
            var configuration = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("extensionFiletypes") as FilenameExtensionTypeConfiguration;
            return configuration ?? new FilenameExtensionTypeConfiguration();
        }

    ...
}
```

Comment: You suspect or you checked with a debugger?

Comment: You haven't given us enough information to diagnose the problem. What is the name of the assembly `Models.Config.FilenameExtensionTypeConfiguration` is in? That's not going to compile unless you excluded a lot of code we need to see where you put “...”.

Comment: Yes, I checked with a debugger.

Comment: The assembly is named `Models`. 

The `FilenameExtensionTypeConfiguration` class contains two other methods, and there are two other classes, one which inherits `ConfigurationElementCollection` and one which inherits `ConfigurationElement`. I changed `Models.Config` to `Models` and commented out the two methods. The code compiles and still returns `null`.